# JavaScript - How to run a function when something besides a particular button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have a menu which I want to show/toggle when a button is clicked and hide when some part of the document besides the button is clicked.  I've been trying a couple things, as you can see here:

```
// $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function()
// {
    // $('.dropdown-menu').show();
// });
$(document).click(function()
{
    // if ($(this).hasClass('dropdown-toggle'))
        // $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
    if ($(this).not('[dropdown-toggle]'))
        $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
});
```

If I uncomment the top part, for some reason the menu will toggle when a part of the document besides the button is clicked and won't do anything when the button is clicked.  If I keep that part commented and uncomment the first if statement (even if I replace the 'toggle' with 'show'), the button will toggle no matter what part of the document I click.

Edit: I solved part of the problem.  It looks like when I uncomment the top part (the click listener for the dropdown-toggle class), the menu shows and then immediately toggles, so it hides.  If I change 'show' to 'hide' I make it so that the menu shows when the button is clicked and toggles otherwise.  However, I want to do almost the opposite.  I want to toggle when the button is clicked and only hide when some other part of the document is clicked.  It seems the "hasClass()" and ".not([])" aren't recognizing the dropdown-toggle as being a class of the thing that's being clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Call `.toggle()` within `click` handler chained to `$(".dropdown-toggle")`; within `click` handler chained to `$(document)`  use `.hasClass()` or  `.is()` to check if `event.target` is `.dropdown-toggle`, chain `.hide()`

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggle();
});

$(document).on("click", function(event) {
 if (!$(event.target).hasClass(".dropdown-toggle")) $(event.target).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  The event part was the part I needed.